# how auto-run an app when i unlock the screen

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, mobile

i want to open  my app directly when i unlock the screen i use the ACTION_USER_PRESENT but dont' work this my code,

the ScreenReciver file

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG,"||||||||||||||||||");
        System.out.println("Received broadcast: " + intent.getAction());
        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)||intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)||intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(launchIntent);
        }


    }
```

the manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver"
            android:exported="true"  android:directBootAware="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_UNLOCKED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot start activities from the background on modern versions of Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts), except in limited circumstances.

Comment: any solution to open app when unlock screen??\